# Editor Window Missing - Only seeing timeline

Tags: 3d-view

Sigh, every time I try to figure out Blender, I lose an hour because of something nutty. I'm a Lightwave user, but giving Blender a go. I tried to set up 4 views for Top/Front/Side/Perspective viewing, like in Lightwave Modeler, but after watching tutorials, I decided to reduce the windows down to one view again.

Well, I only made about 5 more tiny views, and eventually learned how to join views. Now that I've done that, I wound up with one large view with ONLY the timeline.

[image]

No matter what I try, I can only expand the console at the top, or move the boundaries between what you see. How do I get the default view back?

Comment: Good Work on your answer below.  A suggestion. See a good video on a video site such as youtube, as a random example. Search Blender UI interface navigation or something like that.  I have seen some good 3rd party videos, its worth it.  You will get a more complete understanding then a single question here.  Then come back with a really difficult question to stump everyone.

You will save time and anguish by seeing a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, found it after much clicking, there is a small control on the bottom menu of a view which allows selecting a number of different elements. In my screenshot, it is in the lower-left. Clicking it and selecting 3D View returned the 3D editor.

I'd still like to know, though, if there is a reset to default.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out :) Here's [a guide](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Window_system/Arranging_frames) if you are still wondering about some things.. There isn't a quick reset to default, but if you really get stuck you can: 1. Save 2. Reload the startup .blend (Ctrl N) 3. Open the file again with *load UI* disabled in the bottom right of the file manager.

Comment: Ooooops. "Load UI" is in the bottom left hand corner (on my setup) of the file manager, not the bottom right.

Comment: @brasshat Gah! I can't seem to type anything right :P You are right again :) (though it *can* be on the right if you press F5 with the cursor over the sidebar..)

Comment: Well, you had the "right" idea.

Answer (score 1):

But sometimes you want the timeline editor visible at the same time as the 3D viewport. The widget in the extreme upper right and lower left hand corner of every window will divide that window, and you can put the editor window associated with any item in the editor window menu you referenced as the "small control" in any window. Using this, you would select the widget in the upper right or lower left, and split the window, and assign the desired window type--in the case that raised your question, the 3D viewport window--to that window.

Yes, there are a couple of ways to "reset". One is to save the file you're working on, and open a New file (from the file menu, or by pressing CTRL-Nkey, and then append the items from the file you were working on into the new file. Another is to use the option "Load Factory settings", also from the file menu. BUT BE WARNED: "Load factory settings" is a nuclear option, it will revert any other changes you may have made in user preferences back to the default, and most of the time this will NOT be what you want to do.